# CSS Can't float left

Tags: css, html

Hi i have tried allot ways how to fix this, but i cant float div to left side. When i create div its automatically stacks in right top corner and i cant move it only with padding and margin.

My **index.php** example need to **float:left** div with class **language**:

```
<body class="menu">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            Show menu
        </div>
        <div class="language">
            Select lang
        </div>
        <header>
            <nav class="menu-side">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/upload">Home</a></li>
                    <li>Login</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload" class="upload">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Upload files</legend>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" required multiple>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
            </fieldset>

            <div class="bar">
                <span class="bar-fill" id="pb"><span class="bar-fill-text" id="pt"></span></span>
            </div>

            <div id="uploads" class="uploads">
                Uploaded links will apear here.
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <footer>
        Created by Revix © 2014
    </footer>
</body>
```

And my css is:

```
html, body {    height: 100%;   margin-top: 0; }

body {  font-family: "Georgia", serif; }

.upload {   width:500px;    background: #f0f0f0;    border: 1px solid #ddd;     padding: 20px;  vertical-align: center;     margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto; }

.upload fieldset {  border: 0;  padding: 0;     margin-bottom: 10px; }

.upload fieldset legend {   font-size: 1.2em;   margin-bottom: 10px; }

footer {    background-color: cornflowerblue;   text-align: center;     vertical-align: middle;     min-width: 542px; }

.wrapper {  min-height: 100%;   margin-bottom: -100px;  clear: both; }

.wrapper:after {    content: "";    display: block; }

.wrapper:after, footer {    height: 100px; }

header {    position: fixed;    margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto; }

.uploads a, .uploads span {     display: block; }

.bar {  width: 100%;    background: #eee;   padding: 3px;   margin-bottom: 10px;    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);     border-radius: 3px;     box-sizing:border-box; }

.bar-fill {     height: 20px;   display: block;     background: cornflowerblue;     width: 0;   border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-transition:width 0.8s ease;     -moz-transition:width 0.8s ease;    -o-transition:width 0.8s ease;  transition:width 0.8s ease; }

.bar-fill-text {    color:#fff;     padding: 3px; }

.language {     float: left;    position: absolute;     width: 80px;    padding: 3px; }
```

If you wanna to see my web site: [Here](http://revix.no-ip.biz/upload)

Can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: PLease provide a jsfiddle link for this.

Comment: And please reduce this to some smaller example which shows the same problem. The stuff you posted is too big and too complex to easily spot the problem.

Comment: Oh, and _which_ div should float left? Because some do, actually: http://jsfiddle.net/5YnN7/  Here I see the menu und the language _on the left side_.

Comment: thanks for tying to help :) aisin helped already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this effect? Please see my demo.

Please paste your code to jsbin.com next time. Otherwise it's not convenient for us to resolve your problem.

http://jsbin.com/yivat/1

Comment: yes something like that :) can you advise me how should i do this? but in other side

Comment: @Mik Pls see code in that demo, I only changed css of .language

Comment: @Mik The principle is set .language to fixed, set it's left position to right: 50%, then set margin-right, margin-right value = (half width of id="upload") + (1/4 width of .language).

Comment: i have question, is this kind of css mix will be enough to work with tablet device?

Comment: It works under your: (id="upload"' width) < (1024 - (width of .language)).

Comment: Because usually tablet's(ipad) screen width is 1024 px.

Answer (score 1):

float:left and position:absolute doesn't work.

remove position:absolute

```
.language {     float: left;   width: 80px;    padding: 3px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting these elements in my browser they have all the CSS attribute `position:absolute;` set, which sets them at a absolute position within the window. But these elements seem to have no `left` and `top` position set which sets you all elements to window position 0,0 which is left top corner. 
I would recommend to set the position to relative `position:relative;` or define specific positions for your html elements.

Comment: i have tried posiotion:relative and left:px but in diferent resolution its looks diferent.

Answer (score 0):

Floating left on a absolute positioned element will not work. Try relative to float it or position it on your page with top:px left:px;

Comment: i have tried now with left:px and posiotion:absolute/relavtive. didnt helped... :(

Comment: oh did with relative and left/top but i diferent resolution it looks diferent.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean literally top:px; or left:px; . I meant use top:30px; and left:30px; and adjust the numbers within each of those to get your div where you want it to be if you are going to use position:absolute;  if you use position:relative; however, then your float:left; or float:right;  will work. Sorry for the confusion.